# Deployed Android App not working with database

Tags: android, blazor, maui, hybrid

I have a strange situation where I developed an Android App for a Samsung Tablet that is not working as intended. The User registration step (first step of the app) is not working and is generating a null error.
During the development phase, the MAUI Blazor Hybrid App was thoroughly tested on Windows and Samsung tablets; all emulators ran successfully as well. However, after deploying (a full install of the .apk file) the App on the same development Tablet, the App launched successfully but the user registration failed with a Null error.  It seems as though the database is not getting found (created) as it should or did during development.

I am registering the database with the following path:

```
    public class SQLiteDatabase:DbContext
    {
        public static string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "ActivityData.db3");
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {          
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={dbPath}");
        }
    }

// and properly setup the injection service in the MauiProgram.cs:
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<SQLiteDatabase>();
```

Is there a special way to setup the database for Android? What else can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Maui provide the local database for developers to use. You can check this document to use [SQLite NuGet package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-8.0).

First, you need to add the SQLite NuGet package and config the data. The [sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-8.0#configure-app-constants) includes a Constants.cs file that provides common configuration data.

Second, you need to create a database access class.

```
public class TodoItemDatabase
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

    public TodoItemDatabase()
    {
    }

    async Task Init()
    {
        if (Database is not null)
            return;

        Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
        var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>();
    }
    ...
}
```

Last, you can use the methods below to manipulate the data.

```
 public async Task<TodoItem> GetItemAsync(int id)
    {
        await Init();
        return await Database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        await Init();
        if (item.ID != 0)
            return await Database.UpdateAsync(item);
        else
            return await Database.InsertAsync(item);
    }

    public async Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        await Init();
        return await Database.DeleteAsync(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply; however, I am working on a MAUI Blazor Hybrid project and could not get that database approach to work.  It generates the following error:
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The type initializer for 'WinRT.ActivationFactory`1' threw an exception.)'
If you create a new MAUI Blazor Hybrid from VS2022 (.NET8). and add the SQLLite packages as the sample recommends and create a data page and constant, ete. the Database initial connection fails.

Comment: In addition, I did discover that the Sample Database Storage location may be problematic for mobile devices because ias it stands in the Sample, the following warning is displayed:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Warning CA1416 This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'FileSystem.AppDataDirectory' is only supported on: 'Windows' 10.0.17763.0 and later. CroctailsDailyActivity (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\Source\repos\Croctails\CroctailsDailyActivity\Data\SQLiteDatabase.cs 11 Active

Comment: You can try to use this path `string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "database.db3");` for the Android platform.